# Is anyone using Microsoft Software Licensing and Protection Services (SLP) in production?

Tags: .net, licensing, performance

Microsoft has come out with this fairly new technology that I am considering using for a .NET 3.5 application.  I am curious, is anyone using this technology already?  I am worried that the use of the secure virtual machine will negatively affect performance.  Also, the way Microsoft advertises the product, it seems as though the licensing integration is very seamless and does not require any development work in the code.  It seems like a great product but I want to make sure I know of any pitfalls before committing to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft announced today that they [are not accepting any new customers](http://blogs.zdnet.com/microsoft/?p=1624) for SLP. Sounds like the whole program is going down the drain... I'm glad my company didn't sign up for it yet!

Comment: Can you please link to the announcement?  I looked on www.microsoft.com/slps and did not see any announcement.

Comment: http://blogs.zdnet.com/microsoft/?p=1624
"Microsoft has halted — temporarily, according to company officials — sales of its Software Licensing and Protection (SLP) Services product."

Answer (score 5):

Seems as http://www.inishtech.com has taken over...

Comment: Inishtech has taken over and the service is fully functional. Works great, no problems with the service.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that SLP does not support .NET 3.5 at the moment.

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3526285&SiteID=1

Your best bet would be to implement an auxiliary DLL containing SLP API calls in .NET 2.0 or 3.0, secure it and add it as a reference to your .NET 3.5 app.

Comment: The cited link is broken **Disclaimer**: *I work for Inishtech*. In general, even from back in the Microsoft days, 3.5 was and is supported (including 2.0+3.0 2.0). It is possible that the referenced thread referred to a lack of x64 support (resolved in 2009) and/or a lack of generics support (resolved in 2009/10). The current offering supports all the way up to 4.5.2 (though .NET 1.1 support was dropped in 2011)